# Is my situation a good case to use GL_STATIC_DRAW?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have a textured polygon mesh that I plan to be move-able based on the user's various inputs.
For example: the user can move the vertices in various directions. But the number of vertices and the texture coordinates will always be constant.

Is this a good situation to use GL_STATIC_DRAW, or should i use something else, like GL_STREAM_DRAW?

Comment: There's a good explanation [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object#Buffer_Object_Usage)

Comment: Do you actually want to offset each position on the CPU for some reason, rather than applying the transformation on the GPU?

Comment: @Nicol. If at all possible, i would definitely want to take advantage of the GPU. But how do I know whatever manipulations i apply to my vertices occur on the CPU or GPU? Right now i have no plan to offset each position. Instead, Im currently only thinking about apply transformation(s), like scale, rotate, and translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your situation is not a good case to use GL_STATIC_DRAW. As h4lcOn's link suggests you should use dynamic or stream. Though if I understand correctly what you are trying to do I wouldn't even use VBO at all. There will not be much overhead (if any at all) if you push the coordinates every draw call for a simple polygon. Use a VBO in cases when you have a large quantity of polygons or when you make large amount of draw calls with the same vertex data in a single frame.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating a VBO every time the vertices are moved, I would suggest using transformations. With transformations, you can create a matrix that can translate, rotate, or scale the vertices by simply multiplying the transformation matrix by the position vector. This multiplication can be done on the graphics card with a GLSL shader. Using this method, your vertex buffer would never have to change.

I would suggest reading this article for more information on how to use transformations in OpenGL: https://open.gl/transformations